# Construction of 2-limits in 2-categories

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, limits-colimits, 2-categories

Limits in a category can be built as a combination of the basic limits that are products and equalizers. Is there a similar construction for 2-limits in a 2-category? If yes, is it from products and equalizers, or some other basic limits? How do you, for example, built a comma object (a special case of 2-limit) using this construction? How does it instantiate in the 2-category of 1-categories?

Comment: The 2-limit of a 2-functor $F$ weighted by a 2-functor $W$ in the 2-category of categories is the functor category $[W,F]$. This is in Kelly's Elementary observation on 2-categorical limits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need more than products and equalisers, but only a bit more: it is enough to have products, equalisers, and cotensors with $\mathbf{2}$ (the free arrow, i.e. the category $\{ 0 \to 1 \}$). First of all, because every category is obtained as an iterated conical colimit of diagrams starting from copies of $\mathbf{1}$ and $\mathbf{2}$, it follows that you have cotensors with any category. Then, by enriched category theory, we get all 2-limits.

For example, given $f : X \to Z$ and $g : Y \to Z$ in a 2-category, the comma object $(f \downarrow g)$ can be constructed as the conical limit of the following diagram,
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@. @. Z \\
@. @. @VV{g}V \\
@. \mathbf{2} \pitchfork Z @>>> Z \\
@. @VVV \\
X @>>{f}> Z
\end{CD}$$
where the two arrows $\mathbf{2} \pitchfork Z \to Z$ are induced by the two functors $\mathbf{1} \to \mathbf{2}$.

All that said, a word of caution: what I said applies only to strict 2-limits, which can be quite different from bilimits. To construct bilimits one needs instead (bicategorical) products, inserters, and equifiers.

Comment: For the notions of inserters and equifiers mentioned by Zhen Lin and for  the construction of lax and pseudo limits, see sections 4 and 5 resp. of Max Kelly's [Elementary observations on $2$-categorical limits](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=998024).

For the construction of bilimits, see Ross Street's [Correction to: "Fibrations in bicategories''](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=903151).

Comment: I am particularly interested in the case of bilimits. Is there a general formula to construct any bilimit from products, inserters, and equifiers? (like the formula that appears in the existence theorem for limits [Mac Lane, Categories for the Working Mathematician, Chapter V, Section 2, Theorem 2])

Comment: @Bob Yes, construction of a bilimit is as the ``descent object'' of a certain truncated cosimplicial diagram - see the bottom of page 55 of the article of Street I referenced above. The cosimplicial diagram is built out of (bicategorical) products and cotensor products, and one can construct descent objects by (bicategorical) inserters and equifiers. For the case of pseudo limits this is spelled out in the article of Kelly, see Prop. 5.2. and its antecedent propositions. (Note that Kelly does not mention descent objects by name, but the construction is the same.)

Comment: The answer by Zhen Lin and the references by @AlexanderCampbell are very useful. In the special case of the (strict) 2-category of small 1-categories, what are the basic limits needed to construct all kinds of limits (strict 2-limits and bilimits)?

Comment: The answer is again products, equalizers and cotensors with $\mathbf{2}$, because bilimits can be calculated as strict 2-limits. The weighted bilimit $\{F,G\}_{bi}$ (where $F,G : \mathcal{A} \to \textbf{Cat}$ are 2-functors) is equivalent to the strict 2-limit $\{QF,G\}$, where $QF$ is a flexible/cofibrant replacement of the weight $F$.